# Join with tabel level data conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 2 tables, when i join those i need matching records with avilable conditions in table 2

[image]

for record empid:106 the query should be like below

select A.* from  tbl1 A join tbl2 B on a.empid=b.empid
and condition 1 and condition 2

conditions need to be taken dynamically.

Comment: _... conditions need to be taken dynamically._ Exactly, you need to use dynamic sql. And since you include an example using incorrect syntax (e.g., =!) you need to consider how to handle such problems. But this seems to be a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) that will likely lead to misery since the join is conditional for every single row in TBL 1

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way you can build and execute a dynamic statement given your example. It's not an end-all, there are conditions that are not handled (e.g., what if no rows exist in TBL2 for the employee?).

```
/* CREATE MOCK-UP TABLES/DATA */

CREATE TABLE TBL1 ( [emp_id] int, [name] varchar(3), [sal] int, [dept] int );
CREATE TABLE TBL2 ( [empid] int, [fclo] varchar(4), [cond] varchar(10), [operator] varchar(3) );

INSERT INTO TBL1 ( [emp_id], [name], [sal], [dept] ) VALUES
    ( 101, 'AAA', 2000, 10 ),
    ( 102, 'BBB', 5000, 20 ),
    ( 103, 'CCC', 9000, 10 ),
    ( 104, 'DDD', 6010, 20 ),
    ( 105, 'EEE', 4000, 10 ),
    ( 106, 'FFF', 7000, 20 ),
    ( 107, 'GGG', 8000, 30 ),
    ( 105, 'EEE', 4000, 20 );

INSERT INTO TBL2 ( [empid], [fclo], [cond], [operator] ) VALUES
    ( 105, 'dept', '<>10', 'AND' ),
    ( 106, 'sal', '>2000', 'AND' ),
    ( 106, 'dept', '<>10', 'AND' );
```

Build and execute a dynamic statement based on a specific employee.

```
DECLARE @emp int = 106;

    -- Initialize the dynamic statement --
    DECLARE @sql varchar(MAX) = '[emp_id]=' + CAST ( @emp AS VARCHAR(10) );

    -- Build WHERE clause --
    SELECT
        @sql = ISNULL ( @sql, '' ) + ' ' + operator + ' ' + '[' + fclo + ']' + ' ' + cond
    FROM TBL1 AS A
    INNER JOIN TBL2 AS B
        ON A.emp_id = B.empid
    WHERE
        A.emp_id = @emp;

    -- Complete @T_SQL statement --
    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM TBL1 WHERE ' + @sql + ';';

/* PRINT out completed dynamic statement */ 
PRINT @sql;

/* Execute the dynamic statement */
EXEC ( @sql );
```

`PRINT`ing the statement reveals the underlying dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TBL1 WHERE [emp_id]=106 AND [sal] >2000 AND [dept] <>10;
```

The `EXEC`ution of the dynamic SQL returns:

```
+--------+------+------+------+
| emp_id | name | sal  | dept |
+--------+------+------+------+
|    106 | FFF  | 7000 |   20 |
+--------+------+------+------+
```